# Babel: Undefined control sequence \__hook_toplevel selectfont ...size \bbl@xenohyph

Tags: xetex, babel, multilingual

I have the following multilingual document that I compile with XeLaTeX. However, I kept getting the error saying

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\__hook_toplevel selectfont ...size \bbl@xenohyph
```

Any idea what's causing this?

## MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[UTF8]{ctex}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{babel}
  \babelprovide[import]{thai}
  \babelfont[russian]{rm}{Times New Roman}
  \babelfont[arabic]{rm}{Calibri}
  \babelfont[thai]{rm}{FreeSerif}

\begin{document}

谢谢
 
Thank you. 

\foreignlanguage{thai}{จังหวัดนครพนม}

\foreignlanguage{russian}{Спасибо.} 
 
\foreignlanguage{arabic}{ما هو }

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must upgrade (see the bug report [Undefined \bbl@xenohyph with Thai](https://github.com/latex3/babel/issues/182)). Sadly, there is another error, which can be fixed with the following lines just after loading `babel`:

```
\makeatletter
\def\bbl@ifset#1#2#3{% 
  \bbl@ifunset{#1}{#3}{\bbl@exp{\\\bbl@ifblank{\@nameuse{#1}}}{#3}{#2}}}
\makeatother
```